# Parse date with GMT+0300 (EEST)

Tags: java, jsp, parsing, date

I have some code

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    String stringDate = request.getParameter("birthDate");
    System.err.println(stringDate);
    try {
        Date date = df.parse(stringDate);
        patient.setBirthDate(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Date comes in format: `Tue Jul 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)`
So, I have ParseException: Unparseable date.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date so that it looks like this:

```
Tue Jul 01 2014 00:00:00 EEST
```

Simply done by

```
String[] p = date.split(" ");
String z = p[6].replace("(", "");
z = p[6].replace(")", "");
date = p[0] + " " + p[1] + " " + p[2] + " " + p[3] + " " + p[4] + " " + z;
```

Then apply the format

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

Comment: I tried to do simple date `Jul 01 2014`, but
also have `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jul 01 2014"`

Comment: I tried to parse `Jul 01 2014` using `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");`
and also have Exception

Comment: Well that should definitely work.  Can you paste in a test case - try to make it a stand alone test if you can.  I can on think that maybe there are some extra characters being passed in on the request.

Comment: Fixed.
The problem was in Local.
A set Local.ENGLISH and it have parsed great. Thank you!

Now have another problem. How to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date